# Rails 7: Fuzzy FIle Matching for public files/images?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, assets, ruby-on-rails-7

Scenario: I'm uploading images to Rails ad hoc. I have the files linked from the database using a external ID # field (the images need to be attributed to the original artist, and this is the easiest way to do it). The files will be uploaded to `public`.

Problem: Some of the images are `.jpg`, others `.png` (might be others later). I can't put the files under `assets/images` since this requires the asset pipeline to be refreshed each time. `ActionController::Base.helpers.resolve_asset_path(@external.id)` and `image_path(@external.id)` work great when it's in the pipeline since I don't have to specify the exact file extension.

The only way I was able to do it was by concatenating/mapping, such as:

```
image_path("/#{@external.id}.jpg") || image_path("/#{@external.id}.png")
```

Not ideal, and not sure if there's a better way? Later, I'll probably look into another storage solution like a BLOB field or S3 bucket, but I wanted to know if there was a simple way to do it this until then.

Comment: definitely don't store uploaded images in assets/images... they won't survive code update! Rails 7 has its own scheme for uploading/storing/naming images called ActiveStorage. You don't even have to think about naming the files, leave it to Rails. Perfectly OK to store the files on your server, but must be in a dir outside the  Rails hierarchy to survive code update.

Comment: Thanks, @LesNightingill . I've been trying to grasp ActiveStorage. Does it store the BLOB into the database?

Comment: no it doesn't store a blob. It stores a file either on your server or AWS etc. This is generally the way this is done in Rails.